# Replace 2 characters with same value

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I want to remove `,0` and `|` at once from the same value which is here `A300,0|A232,0`

test table

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id   | name                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1   | A300,0|A232,0         |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

```
select REPLACE(t.name, "|", " ") as a,
replace(t.name, ',0', '') as b
from test as t;
```

```
result 
a = A300,0 A232,0 
b= A300|A232
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could achieve what you want by using `REPLACE` twice:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(t.name, '|', ' '), ',0', '') AS yourResult
FROM test as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(,0)|(\|)', '')
FROM test;
```

I.e. simply find `,0` or `|` and replace all found occurences with empty string.

Comment: OP wants a space from a `|`. It can't be done with a single call to regexp_replace.

Comment: @Bohemian Oh, I have not payed attention to this point... in this case nested REPLACE() is the best solution.